# Python 3 cmd.Cmd append space after do_function(): completion

Tags: python, autocomplete, append, space, python-cmd

I'm using the cmd.Cmd library for a command line tool that I'm building and am mildly annoyed that using tab to auto-complete a command, the command line is left at the end of the command instead of appending a space to easily facilitate adding arguments.

```
do_function(self, line):
    print(line)
```

and

```
(Cmd)func[TAB]
```

gives the user;

```
"(Cmd)function"
```

whereas I'd like to see;

```
"(Cmd)function "
```

*with* the space so I can more easily add a value to (in this case) print.

Is there any way to force an appended space after a tab completion?  I assume there's an argument I can set in the cmd.Cmd class to force/allow this... but I can't find any documentation on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know a thing about the cmd module, but the documentation says that the `Cmd` class's stdout will default to `sys.stdout` if not specified. I would try manually calling `sys.stdout.write(' ')` after the auto-complete

Comment: I suppose that would work if I edited the cmd.Cmd class in that library to append a space, but then I'd change all other instances of cmd.Cmd I have on this machine.  It would also require making that modification on any *other* machines I want to use this on...  Thanks for the comment, but I don't think it'll work for my needs.

Comment: If you cannot find another answer, all I can suggest is you make a copy of the main `Cmd` class, and keep it in the same directory of you app. Import that edited class from the file instead of the module.

Comment: You might want to try cmd2, that behaves already like that out of the box.